# Is there always a positive $x$ that satisfies $\cos(n_1x)\leq0$, $\cos(n_2x)\leq0$, $\cos(n_3x)\leq0$ for given distinct positive integers $n_i$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

Prove or disprove:

> Given distinct $n_1$, $n_2$, $n_3$ $\in \mathbb{N}$, \begin{cases} \cos(n_1x)\leq0 \\ \cos(n_2x)\leq0 \\ \cos(n_3x)\leq0\end{cases} has a
> positive solution.

**My first attempt** was by writing each cosine in terms of $\cos(x)$, then by setting $\cos(x) = t$, it's solved like a normal system of inequalities.

This didn't work for me because writing each $\cos(n_jx)$ in terms of $\cos(x)$ gets harder as the $n_j$ increases, and I'm also unable to find a pattern behind their conversion, this doesn't let me find a generalized proof.

**Second attempt** was by using parametric functions:

$\\ \sin{(\alpha)}=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\ \ \ \mbox{where }\ t=\tan{\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}\mbox{ and }\alpha\neq\pi+2k\pi$

$\\ \cos{(\alpha)}=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\ \ \ \mbox{where }\ t=\tan{\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}\mbox{ and }\alpha\neq\pi+2k\pi$

$\\ \tan{(\alpha)}=\frac{2t}{1-t^2}\ \ \ \mbox{where }\ t=\tan\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\mbox{ and }\alpha\neq\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi\ \wedge\ \alpha\neq\pi+2k\pi$

Same problem as the first attempt, I'm unable to generalize their conversion in terms of a fixed $α$, so can't again find a generalized proof.

**A third attempt** was using proof by contradiction:

We suppose no such $x$ exists. Then, for every positive $x,$ at least one of the three cosines is always positive.

... Can't get past this point.

Comment: Interesting, haven't thought about this approach! Even though I have no idea what to do, meaning that I understand the principle behind "finding the absurd", but I don't know from where to attack the problem...

Comment: Especially for future reference: please understand that on this website, your questions get more approval when you supply relevant context. You should've deleted neither your earlier clarification of this problem's background nor and your attempts even if they were futile! [Reposting my comment: Since this forum encourages learning, it is best if you show your thoughts, ideas, and attempt at the problem. Here's a quick guide on how to ask a good Question, which is less likely to get closed/deleted and more likely to get a good Answer: http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813 ]

Comment: @ryang I edited the body of my question and added every attempt I made until now!

Comment: Maybe try first with 1 $c$ value, then 2 $c$ values, then 3 $c$ values.   If that works, I suppose you could try with $N$ $c$ values.  I also assume your $\mathbb{N}$ does not include $0$.

Comment: @Claude The given claim is true; when there are at least four $c$’s, then it is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For each set of positive integers $n_1,n_2,n_3,$
> $$\cos(n_1x),\cos(n_2x),\cos(n_3 x)\leq0$$ has a real solution.

Observation: *if* the statement specifies greater than three positive integers instead, then it is false: a counterexample is $n_4=4.$

**Proof** *(but missing Case 2)*

It suffices to show that for ascendingly-ordered positive integers $a,b,c,$ $$\cos\left(\frac\pi2ax\right),\cos\left(\frac\pi2bx\right),\cos\left(\frac\pi2cx\right)\leq0$$ has a real solution.

Noting that $$\cos\left(\frac\pi2nx\right)\leq0\\\iff\\ x\in\ldots\cup\left[-\frac3n,-\frac1n\right]\cup\left[\frac1n,\frac3n\right]\cup\left[\frac5n,\frac7n\right]\cup\left[\frac9n,\frac{11}n\right]\cup\ldots,$$ there are **four** possible cases:

1. $c\leq 3a:$

   \begin{align}&a<b &\text{and} &&b<c &&\text{and} &&a<c\leq3a<3c\\
      &\frac1b<\frac1a &\text{and} &&\frac3c<\frac3b &&\text{and}
      &&\frac1c<\frac1a\leq\frac3c<\frac3a \end{align}
   $$[\frac1a,\frac3c]\subseteq[\frac1a,\frac3a]\cap[\frac1b,\frac3b]
      \cap[\frac1c,\frac3c]
      \\\cos\left(\frac\pi2ax\right), \cos\left(\frac\pi2bx\right),
      \cos\left(\frac\pi2cx\right)\leq0
      \quad\text{ on } \left[\frac1a,\frac3c\right].$$
2. $\displaystyle b<3a<c<\frac{2ab}{3a-b}:$

   ***This section needs to be filled in; for convenience: Desmos links [1](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fstwlng4vb) & [2](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3bcbjrxsof). I have duplicated the next four lines from Case 3 only so that this Answer is at least a proof of the given statement were it to require only $\mathbf{\mathit{\cos(n_1x),\cos(n_2x)}}$ to be nonpositive.***

   $$a<b<3a<3b \\\frac1b<\frac1a<\frac3b<\frac3a \\
      [\frac1a,\frac3b]\subseteq[\frac1a,\frac3a]\cap[\frac1b,\frac3b]
      \\\cos\left(\frac\pi2ax\right), \cos\left(\frac\pi2bx\right)\leq0
      \quad\text{ on } \left[\frac1a,\frac3b\right].$$
3. $b<3a<c$ and $\displaystyle c\geq\frac{2ab}{3a-b}:$

   $$a<b<3a<3b \\\frac1b<\frac1a<\frac3b<\frac3a \\
      [\frac1a,\frac3b]\subseteq[\frac1a,\frac3a]\cap[\frac1b,\frac3b]
      \\\cos\left(\frac\pi2ax\right), \cos\left(\frac\pi2bx\right)\leq0
      \quad\text{ on } \left[\frac1a,\frac3b\right].$$

   Since $\displaystyle \frac3b-\frac1a=\frac{3a-b}{ab}\geq\frac2c,$ which is the size of the smallest interval on which $\displaystyle\cos\left(\frac\pi2cx\right)$ *must* be somewhere nonpositive, some point in $\displaystyle\left[\frac1a,\frac3b\right]$ in fact contains a solution for $\cos\left(\frac\pi2ax\right),\cos\left(\frac\pi2bx\right),\cos\left(\frac\pi2cx\right)\leq0.$
4. $b\in\big[(2m{+}1)a,(2m{+}3)a\big]$ and $m\in\mathbb Z^+:$

   \begin{align}b&\leq(2m+3)a &\text{and} &&b&\geq(2m+1)a\\
      \frac1a&\leq\frac{2m+3}b &\text{and}
      &&\frac3a&\geq\frac{6m+3}b\\&\leq\frac{4m+1}b &&&&>\frac{4m+3}b\\
      &\frac1a\leq\frac{4m+1}b<\frac{4m+3}b<\frac3a\end{align}
   $$\left[\frac{4m+1}b,\frac{4m+3}b\right]\subseteq
      \left[\frac1a,\frac3a\right]\cap\left[\frac{4m+1}b,\frac{4m+3}b\right]\\
      \cos\left(\frac\pi2ax\right),\cos\left(\frac\pi2bx\right)≤0
      \quad\text{ on } \left[\frac{4m+1}b,\frac{4m+3}b\right].$$

   Since $\displaystyle\frac{4m+3}b-\frac{4m+1}b=\frac2b>\frac2c,$ which is the size of the smallest interval on which $\displaystyle\cos\left(\frac\pi2cx\right)$ *must* be somewhere nonpositive, some point in $\displaystyle\left[\frac{4m+1}b,\frac{4m+3}b\right]$ in fact contains a solution for $\cos\left(\frac\pi2ax\right),\cos\left(\frac\pi2bx\right),\cos\left(\frac\pi2cx\right)\leq0.$

Comment: @ryang ok, but then I don't understand why I can use this proof by contradiction to prove the original claim but with an extra $c_4$, even though this time the claim is false...?

Comment: @ryang Example: $c_1=1, c_2=2, c_3=3, c_4=4$, it's not true that there exists an $x$ such that each cosine is $\leq 0$, but I can apply the same proof by contradiction and it works, but it's not possible...?

Comment: just for the record: the OP's attempts (supplied under the Question) and context (they created this exercise themself) preceding this Answer has been deleted due to clutter.

Comment: @ryang Thanks again! One thing: why did you add $\frac{\pi}{2}$ inside the cosine? I suppose it is a convenient equivalence to prove your claim more easily, but why it's equivalent?

Comment: @AndreaFrasca $\cos\left(\frac\pi2ax\right)$ is nonpositive at $p$ iff $\cos\left(ax\right)$ is nonpositive at $\frac\pi2p.$ Using this equivalence pre-processes the proof to make it more readable.

Comment: @ryang thanks a lot for all your hard work! It's a little sad that all of this is necessary for such a "relatively simple" claim, but ehi, if it works it works!

Comment: @ryang: This comment was for the O.P. instead of for you. I apologize for  my distraction. I see now that I have misunderstood the question. Regards.

Comment: @ryang sorry, I forgot about your comment. I created this question because of my work on an attempted proof at the Lonely runner conjecture, even though it sadly didn't help me. The proof is currently on Reddit, on r/math, hoping someone will read it and give reviews, hoping to have got some kind of results!

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume $n_1<n_2<n_3$. We know that for $\frac{π}{2n_1}≤x≤\frac{3π}{2n_1}$, $\cos(n_1x)≤0$.

Now consider $\cos(n_2x)$. $\frac{π}{2n_2}<\frac{π}{2n_1}$ as $n_1<n_2$. If $\frac{3π}{2n_2}>\frac{π}{2n_1}$ we would immediately have a region where both $\cos(n_1x)≤0$ and $\cos(n_2x)≤0$, viz. $\frac{π}{2n_1}≤x≤\frac{3π}{2n_2}$. Thus let's assume the opposite, that $\frac{3π}{2n_2}<\frac{π}{2n_1}$ $\implies 3n_1<n_2$.

Now, the next interval on which $\cos(n_2x)≤0$ is $\frac{5π}{2n_2}≤x≤\frac{7π}{2n_2}$. But, $n_2>3n_1>\frac{5n_1}{3}$ $\implies 5n_1<3n_2 \implies \frac{5π}{2n_2}<\frac{3π}{2n_1}$. Thus for $\frac{5π}{2n_2}≤x≤\frac{3π}{2n_1}$ both $\cos(n_1x)≤0$ and $\cos(n_2x)≤0$.

Similarly we can argue for $\frac{5π}{2n_1}<x<\frac{7π}{2n_1}$. This may seem redundant, but notice that we can repeat our entire argument but this time take $n_2$ and $n_3$ instead. The interval $\frac{π}{2n_1}<x<\frac{3π}{2n_1}$ contains $\frac{5π}{2n_2}<x<\frac{7π}{2n_2}$. Now in this interval apply this argument but for $n_2$ and $n_3$ instead.

> Similarly we can argue for $\frac{5π}{2n_1}<x<\frac{7π}{2n_1}$

From this we can also see why the claim would not be true for $4$ $n$s (Hint: for the fourth $n$ we will have to look at the next interval $\frac{9π}{2n_1}<x<\frac{11}{2n_1}$, for which the ratio $\frac{5}{3}$ we got will change to something bigger than $3$)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131446/discussion-on-answer-by-amadeus-is-there-always-a-positive-x-that-satisfies).